# Can we get MathML output from MathJax

Tags: mathjax, mathml

I was wondering if there are ways to convert `MathJax` output to `MathML`.

I read through several articles that saying `MathJax` supports `MathML`. I can also see the option '`Show MathML`' when I right click the `MathJax` formulas. My question is, can I get the `MathML` output to the webpage from `MathJax`? I am not familiar with `MathJax` and I am not sure how it works. Any resources or tutorial pages would have been nice!

Answer (score 5):

@Peter, I think the OP may be asking how to get a MathML string from MathJax, rather than how to insert the MathML tags into the page directly.  So perhaps the discussion on the MathJax forums that describes [how to use toMathML](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/unL8IjcrTto/DjHpH4BbPRcJ) will do the trick.

The basic idea is to get the element jax (using `MathJax.Hub.getAllJax`) for the math you want to convert, then to call its `toMathML` method.  But you need to use some care for this, as `toMathML` can operate asynchronously.  The link above goes through the details.

**EDIT**: The [MathJax-node](http://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node/) project allows you to do this from the command line, so you might want to check that out as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have written some code check it out:
First include "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" and "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"

```
var JaxToML = {
 toMathML: function(jax, callback) {
     var mml;
     try {
         mml = jax.root.toMathML("");
     } catch (err) {
         if (!err.restart) {
             throw err
         } // an actual error
         return MathJax.Callback.After([JaxToML.toMathML, jax, callback], err.restart);
     }
     MathJax.Callback(callback)(mml);
 },
 convert: function(AjaxText, callback) {
     var tempDiv = $('<div style="width:455px;height:450px:border-width:thick;border-style:double;"></div>').appendTo("body").html(AjaxText)[0];
     MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, tempDiv]); //first place in Q
     MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() { //wait for a callback to be fired
         var jax = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax(tempDiv);
         for (var i = 0; i < jax.length; i++) {
             JaxToML.toMathML(jax[i], function(mml) {//alert(jax[i].originalText + "\n\n=>\n\n"+ mml);
                 AjaxText = AjaxText.replace(jax[i].originalText, mml);
             });
         }
         $(tempDiv).remove();
         AjaxText = AjaxText.replace(/\(/g,""); //notice this escape character for ( - i.e it has to be \( , know why it is beacuse JS will treat ) or ( as end/begin of function as there are no quotes here.
         AjaxText = AjaxText.replace(/\)/g,""); //notice this escape character for ) - i.e it has to be \)
         AjaxText = AjaxText.replace(/\\/g,"");
         callback(AjaxText);
     });
 },
```

};

Usage :

```
JaxToML.convert(AjaxText, function(mml) {
         alert(mml);             
     });
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Comment: It's good solution but I found the bug: try please formula $${c}_{\mathrm{w}}{\rho }_{\mathrm{w}}{V}_{\mathrm{g}}\left({t}_{\mathrm{g}}-t\right)={c}_{\mathrm{w}}{\rho }_{\mathrm{w}}{V}_{\mathrm{x}}\left(t-{t}_{\mathrm{x}}\right)$$ . Round brackets are gone..

Answer (score 0):

The MathJax documentation on [configuring MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html) is probably the place to start reading. You can configure the [output jax per browser](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/MMLorHTML.html).

A word of caution. There's a reason why MathJax does not use to MathML output on *any* browser right now: browser support isn't quite there yet. (This will change as browsers catch up and MathJax can start to leverage their native support.) So make sure your content actually renders ok.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is now yes, check out MathJax [docs for MathML Support](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output/mathml.html)