# How to convert Latex to mathml

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, latex, mathml

This my latex code. How to convert this to MATHML code using jQuery, JavaScript or PHP

```
$${\pi_{ij}}={\rm{R}}SBU_{ij}^L-{\rm{R}}SBU_{ij}^H={q_{ap}}(f_{ij}^L-f_{ij}^H)/{N_{ap}}.$$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not a translation service. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to write a question. In this case post effort and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the JavaScript library MathJax (https://www.mathjax.org/)

**(A)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
Your test: $${\pi_{ij}}={\rm{R}}SBU_{ij}^L-{\rm{R}}SBU_{ij}^H={q_{ap}}(f_{ij}^L-f_{ij}^H)/{N_{ap}}.$$
</body>
</html>
```

**(B)**

And if you actually need the MathML then mathJax offers that functionality as well as described in [their docs](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.5-latest/toMathML.html)

Moreover, if you are already working with NodeJS then you could have a look at [MathJax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node/) as mentioned in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387458/can-we-get-mathml-output-from-mathjax). It allows different input syntax (e.g. TeX) and offers different outputs (e.g. MathML), see their GIT.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and show a real example

Comment: it's good.. But it's convert to the html code. need to convert as MATHML

Comment: Check the edited answer, maybe the referenced project is suitable for you.