# How to put Latex on Blogger in better way?

Tags: html, ms-word, latex, blogger

I found out that I can copy equation from Symbolab or Word 365 and paste it to Blogger with a kind of HTML codes I got from [How to convert Latex to mathml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040979/how-to-convert-latex-to-mathml).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
Your test: $${\pi_{ij}}={\rm{R}}SBU_{ij}^L-{\rm{R}}SBU_{ij}^H={q_{ap}}(f_{ij}^L-f_{ij}^H)/{N_{ap}}.$$
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Preview of my blog post with Latex]

It converts my Latex to MathML, but I cannot see my equation in Blogger editor if I switch HTML editing mode to usual writing mode. I cannot see where my mathematical equation is when I want to type some paragraphs for my Science Web Novel without getting distracted by HTML codes.

[image: The equation is invisible!]

Comment: Have a try with [**KaTeX**](https://katex.org/), you only have to change the link in your header. If KaTeX gives you this feature, consider it, since it's also very lighter :)

Comment: Thank you, but it still not showing in usual writing display. But yesterday I found MathML in this blog:https://www.airinaa.com/2018/04/add-mathjax-beautiful-mathematic.html could help me to add Latex equation by adding $ symbol.

Comment: Yes, dollar sign is one of the math delimiters. Use them properly to get inline math and display style math

Comment: Hello. I don't know how to solve this, but I do have some suggestions because it seems like your code is not included correctly. You are including code from the former MathJax CDN; it has been deprecated since 2017. This also means that you are using version 2 of MathJax. Consider using version 3 instead, a complete rewrite, which is much faster and accessible. (You can go to https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted to copy the code.) By the way, KaTeX is a great library, but it's not much faster than MathJax 3, and is also less accessible and has less features.